# Python. Discord.py. Wavelink YouTube Playlist

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Я хочу, чтобы бот определял, какой плейлист включать или трек нормальный. Я написал этот код, но выводит такой код. Я новичок в питоне. Помоги мне, пожалуйста

```
res = await vc.node.get_tracks(cls=wavelink.Track, query="название песни")
        track = wavelink.Track(res[0].id, res[0].info)
        await vc.play(track)
        
        res1 = await vc.node.get_tracks(cls=wavelink.Playlist, query="название песни")
        playlist = wavelink.Playlist(res1[0].id, res1[0].info)
        await vc.play(playlist)
        
        try:
            res = await vc.node.get_tracks(cls = wavelink.Track, query = search)
        except:
            res1 = await vc.node.get_playlist(cls = wavelink.Playlist, query = search)
```

Ошибка : `local variable 'vc' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Он не понимает, что такое vc. Из кода это тоже не видно. Лучше бы разобраться в логике кода.

Comment: я добавил команду vc = ctx.voice_client и он вывел мне error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'node'

Comment: Вам надо понимать, что вы делаете. Копирование строк кода без анализа не поможет. Обратите внимание на NoneType. Нормальный объект с таким типом быть не должен. Удачи!